# why am I not getting a 4 in this list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list = [9,8,7]
for k in range (3):
    my_list.insert(-k,k+1)
print(my_list)
```

I am getting: `[1,9,8,3,2,7]`
I have changed the insert and tested it with different numbers and do not understand. I thought -1 would insert at the end of the list.

Comment: `range(3)` will go only from 0 to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `insert(i, x)` function insert a new item with value x in the list before position i. my_list[-1] is the end element, so my_list.insert(-1, 2) will insert before the end element 7.

```
for k in range (3): my_list.insert(-k,k+1) 

my_list.insert(0,1) --> my_list = [1, 9, 8, 7]
my_list.insert(-1,2) --> my_list = [1, 9, 8, 2, 7]
my_list.insert(-2,3) --> my_list = [1, 9, 8, 3, 2, 7]
```

Comment: That break down is clear thanks. I was also starting at 1 instead of 0. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`4` is not inserted because you are doing `(k+1)` on `insert`.
And you called `range(3)`. `range(3)` returns `[0, 1, 2]`.

So, it never reaches till `4`.

And if you want to insert at the end use `my_list.append(k)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`-1` will insert into the last but one,if you want insert at the end of the list, use `your_list.append(val)`